# How to stop boostrap modal video autoplays on page refresh

Tags: video, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am working with bootstrap modal here this code is working fine when I use URL. But when I'm trying to play the video from my local directory. Example when i use `<iframe width="1280" height="720" id="sampleVideo" src="assets/sample.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` its not working fine.The issue is whenever page refresh video automatically plays before click on play video button.
I tried using `HTML5 video tag` also but the problem is with the bootstrap model that is not working. And also `?rel=0`. I don't want to use any plugins.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modal").modal('hide');
  var url = $("#sampleVideo").attr('src');

  $(".modal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#sampleVideo").attr('src', '');
  });

  $(".modal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#sampleVideo").attr('src', url);
  });
});
```

```css
.teaser {
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.teaser .modal-dialog {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.teaser .modal {
  padding-right: 0!important;
}

.teaser iframe {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.teaser .modal-body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.teaser .close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  /* background: blue !important; */
  border: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  right: 3%;
  float: none;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="teaser container-fluid">
  <a href="#videoStory" class="videoBtnbutton more mt-4 d-block" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-fullscreen">Play Video</a>
  <div class="modal modal-fullscreen fade" id="modal-fullscreen" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" id="yt-player">
          <iframe width="1280" height="720" id="sampleVideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScMzIvxBSi4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the working code here [codepen link here](https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/aabzMq)

Comment: Why do you want to fetch the video from the local directory? If the site is online on a server then you can pull the video from URL. Then what is the use of local directory video? Tell me the exact reason behind it. Is your site online?

Comment: Read my question once and I want to use local directory video. And my site is not online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that if you use iframe to insert a local video, browser like Chrome will create elements like:

```
<video controls autoplay name="media">
    <source src="assets/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It will add attribute `autoplay`.

So one way you can handle it is that removing `autoplay` attribute from the element on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sampleVideo").contents().find('video').prop("autoplay", false);
});
```

But you will probably meet an issue that video plays before document ready. A way to mitigate it is to reset video progress:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elem = $("#sampleVideo").contents().find('video')[0];
    elem.autoplay = false;
    elem.pause();
    elem.currentTime = 0;
});
```

For re-opening the modal, you can also add event handler for iframe onload:

```
$('#sampleVideo').on('load', function() {
    var elem = $("#sampleVideo").contents().find('video')[0];
    elem.autoplay = false;
    elem.pause();
    elem.currentTime = 0;
});
```

But I think the real way to deal with it is to use real `video` tag for local resources:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="yt-player">
    <video controls name="media">
        <source src="assets/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".modal").modal('hide');
    var url = $("#sampleVideo").attr('src');

    $(".modal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
        var elem = $("#sampleVideo")[0];
        elem.pause();
        elem.currentTime = 0;
    });

    $(".modal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        var elem = $("#sampleVideo")[0];
        elem.pause();
        elem.currentTime = 0;
    });
});
```

Because url in `src` of the iframe should return an HTML.

Comment: thanks. As you said I tried your code. On page refresh issue solved. But on model close video is continuously playing after model close also.

Comment: @Husna You can try to also add video handling on iframe onload event. But I will still recommend you to use an html link for iframe src.

Comment: i tried like this ` $("#sampleVideo").contents().find('video').prop("autoplay", false);` onload

Comment: when we use `video tag` why modal is not working before when I use iframe my js code is working fine on modal close video is stop playing.

Comment: @Husna try to use video API instead of modifying DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: @Husna you might need currentTime, paused, pause(), play()